# Show Google play by android code

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to intent google play for particular application in android programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=app_package_name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there any way to get the package name manually?

Comment: Yes, when you perform a search in google play yo only have to look at the url. There is the name of the package. For example:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5yb3Zpby5hbmdyeWJpcmRzIl0. The name of the package here is com.rovio.angrybirds

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code to open the play store directly

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>")));
```

Keep in mind that this solution will only works if the play store app is installed on the target device. In the case it is not installed the `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` will be fired. So handle this exception and open the http:// url instead of the market:// one.

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>")));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="<package_name>")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work (the flags are a nice addition if you want the user to come back to your application through the "back"-button instead of browsing through the play store):

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                   Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.package.name"));
                   marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                   startActivity(marketIntent );
```